# BCP Unexpected String Data, Right Truncation

Tags: text, import, character-encoding, azure-sql-database, bcp

Trying to import data into Azure. Created a text file and have tried both comma and tab delimited text files.

Here is the table the text file is to be inserted into:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [first_name] [varchar] (50),
    [last_name] [varchar] (50),
    [dob] [varchar] (10),
    [gender] [char] (1),
    [phone] [char] (10))
```

BCP dbo.Test in C:\Test.txt -S “DBServerName” -d “DBName” -U “UserName” -P “Password” -c -r/r

Have tried saving the text file in different formats and with different encodings, but believe that it’s correct to have it as UTF-16 with UNIX LF.  Any thoughts?  Also, if there are nulls in the data (excluding the Id field), does that need to be specified somehow in the BCP statement? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer? If my answer can be helpful, could you please accept it?Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can reference this document:[Import data into Azure SQL Database with BCP Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-load-from-csv-with-bcp#3-load-the-data).
This tutorial is talking about load data from CSV into Azure SQL Database (flat files).

From the document, we can get that:

**1. Your data file needs to use the ASCII or UTF-16 encoding.**

**2. BCP does not support UTF-8.**

Besides, you can also reference [Format Files for Importing or Exporting Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/format-files-for-importing-or-exporting-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

I have a text data file which one column has null.

[image]

Then I imported this file into my Azure SQL database dbleon1 specified nothing else and succeeded.

My bcp code:

```
bcp tb1 in C:\Users\leony\Desktop\tb1.txt -S *****.database.windows.net -d dbleon1 -U ServerAdmin -P ***** -q -c -t
```

[image]

I checked and the data is imported into `tb2` in database `dbleon1`.
[image]

Hope this helps.